# Reverse for 'communication-detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['communication/communication/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

I wanted to create a new app (communication) in my project that shared very similar properties to my original app (surveys). I essentially copy and pasted the same code into the new app and renamed everything. Unfortunately, now the details page of Communication is broken. The correct pk is showing up in the URL of the page and the views is being accessed correctly. However, the Django debug page is claiming that the pk that has passed through is nothing (''). When I print item.id, it all is correctly displayed.

I've tried changing the view referenced in the urls.py to be a different view that I know works and it is successful. My theory is that somehow my specific view doesn't work?

views.py

```
class CommunicationView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    model = Communication
    fields = ('name', 'language', 'prompt_type')

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return self.object.get_prompt_url()
        return reverse_lazy('communication-prompts', args = (self.object.id,))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get('project'):
            context['project'] = Project.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('project'))
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        # context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get('project'):
            initial['project'] = Project.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('project'))
        return initial.copy()

class CommunicationDetail(CommunicationView, DetailView):
    template_name='communication/communication_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project'] = self.object.project
        print(context)
        return context
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'communication'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include([
        path('', views.CommunicationList.as_view(), name='communication-list'),
        path('add/communication/', views.CommunicationCreate.as_view(), name='communication-create'),
        path('<int:pk>/', include([
            path('', views.CommunicationDetail.as_view(), name='communication-detail'),
            path('run/', views.run_communication, name='run-communication'),
            path('responses/', views.CommunicationResponse.as_view(), name='communication-response'),
            path('prompts/', include([
                path('', views.CommunicationPrompts.as_view(), name='communication-prompts'),
                path('sound/', views.CommunicationPromptSound.as_view(), name='communication-prompt-sound'),
            ])),
            path('questions/', include([
                path('', views.QuestionList.as_view(), name='question-list'),
                path('add/', views.QuestionCreate.as_view(), name='question-create'),
                path('<int:question_pk>/', include([
                    path('', views.QuestionDetail.as_view(), name='question-detail'),
                    path('run/', views.run_question, name='run-question'),
                    path('save/', views.save_response, name='save_response'),
                    path('next/', views.run_question, name='question'),
                    path('update/', views.QuestionUpdate.as_view(), name='question-update'),
                    path('sound/', views.QuestionSound.as_view(), name='question-sound'),
                    path('remove/', views.QuestionDelete.as_view(), name='question-delete'),
                ])),
            ])),
        ]))
    ])),
]
```

communication_list.html

```
  <tbody>
    {% for item in communication_list %}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="{% url 'communication:communication-detail' pk=item.id %}{% if project %}?project={{ item.project.id }}{% endif %}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
      <td>{{ item.project }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'contact-list' %}?communication={{ item.id }}">{{ item.respondents.count }}</td>
      <td><a href="">?</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

models.py

```
class Communication(models.Model):
    VOICE = 'voice'
    SMS = 'sms'
    WHATSAPP = 'whatsapp'
    COMMUNICATION_CHOICES = (
        (VOICE, 'Voice'),
        (SMS, 'SMS'),
        (WHATSAPP, 'WhatsApp'),
    )
    DEFAULT = 'default'
    TEXT = 'text'
    SOUND = 'sound'
    NONE = 'none'
    PROMPT_CHOICES = (
        (DEFAULT, 'Default Prompts'),
        (TEXT, 'Custom Text'),
        (SOUND, 'Custom Sound'),
        (NONE, 'No Prompts')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    communication_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=COMMUNICATION_CHOICES, default=VOICE)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    prompt_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PROMPT_CHOICES, default=DEFAULT)
    welcome_prompt = models.ForeignKey(Prompt, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='welcome_communications')
    text_prompt = models.ForeignKey(Prompt, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='text_communicationes')
    yes_no_prompt = models.ForeignKey(Prompt, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='yes_no_communications')
    numeric_prompt = models.ForeignKey(Prompt, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='numeric_communications')
    goodbye_prompt = models.ForeignKey(Prompt, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='goodbye_communications')
    respondents = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True)

    @property
    def responses(self):
        return QuestionResponse.objects.filter(question__communication__id=self.id)

    @property
    def first_question(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(communication__id=self.id
                                       ).order_by('id').first()
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('communication-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.id})

    def get_prompt_url(self):
        if self.prompt_type == self.TEXT:
            return reverse('communication-prompts', kwargs={'pk':self.id})
        elif self.prompt_type == self.SOUND:
            return reverse('communication-prompt-sound', kwargs={'pk':self.id}) 
        else:
            self.add_prompts(prompts=Prompt.objects.filter(is_default=True))
            return reverse('question-create', kwargs={'pk':self.id})  

    def add_prompts(self, prompts):
        for prompt in prompts:
            setattr(self, '{}_prompt'.format(prompt.category), prompt)
        self.save()
        return self

    def get_prompt(self, kind):
        prompt = getattr(self, '{}_prompt'.format(kind))
        # prompt = getattr(self, '{}_prompt'.format(self.kind.replace('-','_')))
        return prompt.get_twiml_data(self.prompt_type)

    def say_prompt(self, twiml, kind):
        verb, args, kwargs = self.get_prompt(kind=kind)
        getattr(twiml, verb)(*args, **kwargs)
        return twiml
```

Comment: show us the full error trace. you're talking about `item.id` in the communication_list.html template, is that the view that doesn't display properly? Or is it the communications details view (as you say in your question)? In that case, why show us the list template and not the detail template?

Comment: Can you post your `Communication` model please? My suspicion is that if you specify `{% url 'communication:communication-detail' pk=item.pk %}` it should work though.

Comment: dirkgroten, It is the communications details page that is not displaying properly. I showed the code for the list page to show the href being called. I am fairly certain the details page is fine because even when I make the details page very simple html, it still errors out. My suspicion is that there is something wrong when it tries to find the specific pk.

Comment: urbanespaceman, I have added the models.py code to my post. I have tried specifying 'pk' instead of 'id' as well.